# How to hide blank/empty cells from combo box?

Tags: database, combobox, self-hosting

I have a table/query in Access and some cells are empty.

[image: See image]

If I open the Anime combo box there are 3 more empty cells because of the other cells like English Series, Japanese Series and Movie.

[image: ComboBox]

Is there any way to hide the empty cells from the combo box and only show anime? (and the same for the other combo boxes.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click the **Combo Box** and on the bottom press **Properties.**

At the **Data** tab, in the **Row Source** (which is the second one).
There I have added the following string at the end:

***WHERE Anime <> "";***

Now it says:

***SELECT CollectionQuery.[Anime] FROM CollectionQuery WHERE Anime <> "";***

Making it ignore all that is empty and only show fields in the combo box with value.